# VSTS build issue file not found 'git' - Linux private agent

Tags: linux, git, azure-devops

I have installed git 2 in private Linux agent. when I build in vsts using agent,
it shows file not found 'git' error.
please suggest.

Comment: can you reinstall git in your terminal

Comment: works now after yum install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check if git is added in your private agent capabilities list:

In Agent Pools page (https://account.visualstudio.com/_admin/_AgentPool) -> click your agent pool -> select the agent -> Capabilities Tab -> check if git is added.

If git is not added in the capabilities list -> Add capability -> specify git and it’s path -> Save changes.

[image]

Now queue the build again and check if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can reinstall git in your terminal :

```
sudo yum install git
```

To verify if it is properly installed :

```
git --version
```